# Missing and insufficient data read from embedded BMP180 pressure sensor in motion

Tags: sensor, embedded, temperature, data, pressure

[image: Embedded BMP180 Pressure Sensor]

We're building an avionic system which will fly onboard on our rocket. And we have embedded BMP180 Pressure Sensor on our avionic system and we want to get smooth data when it is moving. Our BMP180 data is fine when it is not moving, but "the data from the sensor is not fine when it is moving".

Our question is how can we better read the BMP180 data while it is moving? Thank you for reading...
Attachments

Comment: Would you not expect the pressure reading to be affected by the pressure wave around the rocket? It doesn't sound like an electronics problem to me. What does "the data from the sensor is not fine when it is moving" mean?

Comment: How is it not fine? Is it a problem of reading the data, or the values that the data contains? You present no code or schematics to assess this.

Answer (score 1):

“The BMP180 is based on piezo-resistive technology for EMC robustness, high accuracy and linearity as well as long term stability.”

The piezo factor means it will be sensitive to vibration which is extreme on a rocket.  You will need to characterize if it is suitable for the acceleration noise of this sensor. Then estimate the amount of vibration on the steady acceleration to see if this can be mechanically dampened or averaged if not saturated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing this as an answer because the questions are too many to write as comments.

The details you've provided are:

- BMP180. (Bosch suggests the BMP280, now.) Bosch's datasheet says it is, *"optimized for use in mobile phones, PDAs, GPS navigation devices and outdoor equipment."* It's a *piezo-resistive* sensor. These often use four piezoresistors, one each along the four sides of a square, in a Wheatstone bridge arrangement. I've no reason to say it won't work well in this application (and no reason to say it will work well.)
- You like *"smooth data."* Whatever that means.
- *"The data from the sensor is not fine when it is moving."* Whatever that means.

It could be a software problem and you've done all the right things ensuring that the electronics bay and its ports are arranged according to best practices. It could be that the BMP180 isn't rated to survive, let alone operate well under the higher accelerations and jerk it is likely to experience. It could be, given my own ignorance of these sensors, that you'll need to deal with the fact that piezeresistors are also used (two, this time, instead of four) as accelerometers and that your bridged arrangement co-mingles acceleration sensing along with static pressure sensing. That would have to come out of experimental testing, which is something else you should do if you haven't, already.

What I want to know from you are the following:

1. Did you create a sealed chamber, with proper venting design?
2. Did you include proper static ports, of the right number (hopefully four or more of them), and open to the outside?
3. Did you work out the proper diameter and spacing for the static ports, determined in part on the sealed bay geometry and volume?
4. Did you avoid obstructions and ensure that the static ports are as far away as possible from things like rail buttons, screw heads, launch lugs, the nose-cone, and rocket diameter transitions in order to promote a laminar flow of the air over the static ports?
5. Did you use a sealed bulkhead, located aft of the sealed altimeter bay, to avoid being affected by the very low pressures (near vacuum it may sometimes seem) aftward by the rocket during its flight?
6. Did you use a sealed bulkhead, located forward of the sealed altimeter bay, to avoid pressure variations created bowward by the rocket during its flight?
7. What are you trying to achieve with the data? (I suspect "maximum altitude" confirmation. But you haven't said, so I'm asking.)
8. What does "smooth data" mean to you?
9. What does "not fine" when "it is moving" mean?
10. Have you developed a test plan to validate that this BMP180 sensor is appropriate for your application? Or do you already have good evidence that the BMP180 has been successfully applied in similar situations?
11. Do you have any projected or measured data on the anticipated acceleration and jerk experienced during a rocket flight and do you have any information whatsoever on the BMP180's response when exposed to same?